# cross platform issues in webpages

Tags: php, html, macos, windows-7, joomla

I am developing some basic html pages, i am setting colors of text usimg  color code #e7eddf

it seems fine in windows but seems different in mac.

Can you explain me why its happening and also suggest me some work around for that??

I am using firefox on both the mac and windows

Comment: Web designer? You'll find this question answered better at http://Doctype.com

Comment: This is probably a browser based issue, rather than PC vs Mac problem. Can you add some more details? Which browsers / versions are you using on each platform?

Comment: Windows and Macs will render colours differently, just, depends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macs use 1.8 gamma by default compared to 2.2 on other OS. This was fixed in Snow Leopard which also uses 2.2 now. Read more [here](http://www.gballard.net/psd/go_live_page_profile/embeddedJPEGprofiles.html).